# Safari renders transparent linear gradient with white / white-ish color

Tags: html, css, safari, linear-gradients

I have tried a lot of solutions without success.

I would like to create a linear gradient from left to right, which starts with transparent and ends up in black.

```css
.box1 {
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  margin: 10px;
  max-width: 500px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 30px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #2d2d2d;
  color: red;
}
.box1::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    to right, rgba(255,255,255,0.01), #2d2d2d
  );
}

.box2 {
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  margin: 10px;
  max-width: 500px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 30px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #2d2d2d;
  color: red;
}
.box2::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    to right, rgba(255,255,255,0), #2d2d2d
  );
}

.box3 {
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  margin: 10px;
  max-width: 500px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 30px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(45,45,45,1);
  color: red;
}
.box3::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(45,45,45,1) 100%);
}

.fade1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 75px;
  background: linear-gradient(
    to right, rgba(255,255,255,0), black
  );
}

.box {
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  margin: 10px;
  max-width: 500px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 30px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1">
</div>
<div class="box2">
</div>
<div class="box3">
</div>

<div class="box">
  <span class="fade1"></span>
</div>
```

Also here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zMvvEd) for you.

Chrome renders it the way I want, but on Safari the result is not the same. Instead of having transparent "color" it has white or white-ish color.

[image]

I know transparent keyword has a different behavior on Safari, so I do not use it at all.

Do you guys have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. It turned out on Safari the transparent color should have the same rgb as the end color.

So:

- if the end color is black, the starting color should be rgba(0,0,0,0)
- if the end color is red, the starting color should be rgba(255,0,0,0)

```css
.fade1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 75px;
  background: linear-gradient(
    to right, rgba(0,0,0,0), black
  );
}

.box {
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  margin: 10px;
  max-width: 500px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 30px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  adsfasdfsdafasdfdasfdasfasdfdasfdasfdsfdasf
  <span class="fade1"></span>
</div>
```